# Is the request "lost" if nginx sends a 499 error?

Tags: nginx, timeout

Here's the architecture

Client ----> Load Balancer ---> nginx  -----> application

The application is monothreaded , and synchronous (no async-io fancy things)

The load balancer and nginx both have a 60 seconds timeout

The application only has one endpoint that takes 10 seconds to treat (when calling directly the application), when there's no traffic, a curl through the Loadbalancer takes also 10 seconds (which is normal)

Now during high load, we see a lot of of 499 in the nginx logs associated with a 60~ish reponse time

My current hypothesis is

1. 10 requests arrive in front the loadbalancer
2. the LB forward the 10 requests to nginx and start its timer for the 10
3. Nginx acknowledge the 10 requests starts the timer for the 10, and proxy 1 to the application and the 9 others waits
4. the 1st request finish, nginx forward the 200 response, time taken 10 seconds for nginx and the LB
5. nginx now send the 2nd requests to the application it takes 10 seconds
6. nginx receiv the 200 response, time taken: 20 seconds for nginx and the LB
7. 3rd request => 30 seconds ,  4th request => 40 seconds
8. the 6th request is receive by the application BUT TOO LATE, the LB close the connection, timeout
9. nginx see the closed connection and reply 499
10. same for the 7th, 8th and 9th requests that all appears with a 60 seconds response time

Now my questions:

1. Is my understanding about what is going on correct ?
2. Is the 6th request treated by the application completely?
3. Are the 7th requests above going to be treated by the application or the application will never know there was a 7th and more request ?